# In linux, what is difference between Open firmware device tree and flattened device tree

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

In linux, what is difference between Open firmware device tree and flattened device tree.
How to identify the linux kernel is using which Device tree  OF DT or FDT.

Answer (score 20):

From [here](http://elinux.org/Device_Tree#Open_Firmware):

> [Open Firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Firmware) is a firmware interface specification designed by Sun in the late 1980's, and ported to many architectures. It specifies a runtime OS client interface, an cross platform device interface ([FCode](http://www.openfirmware.info/Forth/FCode)), a user interface, and the Device Tree layout for describing the machine.
>
> FDT is to Open Firmware what DSDT is to ACPI. The FDT reuses Open Firmware's established device tree layout. In fact, Linux PowerPC support uses the same codebase to support both Open Firmware and FDT platforms.

As you can see, Flattened Device Tree (FDT) is a part of Open Firmware. So basically nowadays "Open Firmware Device Tree" and "Flattened Device Tree" are the same thing. More details on Device Tree history can be found in [kernel device tree doc](https://docs.kernel.org/devicetree/usage-model.html#history):

> In 2005, when PowerPC Linux began a major cleanup and to merge 32-bit and 64-bit support, the decision was made to require DT support on all powerpc platforms, regardless of whether or not they used Open Firmware. To do this, a DT representation called the Flattened Device Tree (FDT) was created which could be passed to the kernel as a binary blob without requiring a real Open Firmware implementation. U-Boot, kexec, and other bootloaders were modified to support both passing a Device Tree Binary (dtb) and to modify a dtb at boot time. DT was also added to the PowerPC boot wrapper (arch/powerpc/boot/*) so that a dtb could be wrapped up with the kernel image to support booting existing non-DT aware firmware.

The word "flattened" means "binary", because Device Tree data structure itself is a tree, but when being converted to a binary form it becomes serialized (linear) data. Hence "FDT" refers to Device Tree binary format, not its source code counterpart which is represented in a tree-like view. Both Device Tree source code format and its binary format are described in [Device Tree spec](https://github.com/devicetree-org/devicetree-specification/releases/).

Take a look at [drivers/of/base.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/of/base.c). It was added back in 1996, but functions from it are used for nowadays ARM device tree. So FDT is just a part of OF. That's why all functions for device tree begin with `of_` prefix.

If you need more details, next articles may be useful:

- [Open Firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Firmware)
- [Device Tree](http://elinux.org/Device_Tree)
- [kernel device tree doc](https://docs.kernel.org/devicetree/usage-model.html#history)
- [Device Tree specification](https://github.com/devicetree-org/devicetree-specification/releases/)

Answer (score 0):

[From the same link posted above](https://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Reference#Open_Firmware)

I see that

```
Other names for Flattened Device Tree (FDT) are "binary blob" and ".dtb". 

dtc (Device Tree Compiler) - converts between the human editable device tree source "dts" format and the compact device tree blob "dtb" representation usable by the kernel or assembler source. dtc is also a dtb decompiler.
```

And device tree is human readable source in the format .dts or .dtsi

Hope this is more clear and right.

thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).